# Stop the page Refreshing on every item clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a website, when I press an asp button on page, the page refreshes, i am trying to find a solution that it stop refreshing for every action I do on the pages in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to integrate partial rendering into your Project. You can follow the Walkthrough on this link to get you started. [Understanding Partial Page Updates with ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

> I press an asp button in it, the page refreshes

If you are talking about `ASP.NET` then Well it should, cause you are using a server side button control (see the property `runat = 'server'`) and by design, on click of that button it will submit the request to server (nothing but perform a `postback`) and hence the page refreshes.

If you are solely looking to stop `postback` then use a normal `HTML` button control without `runat = 'server'` property which will not cause a postback.

Else, You can `return false` in `OnClientClick` event of the button like `OnClientClick="return false;"`.

As well you can add the below line in your code bhind

```
btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajaxify your application. you can use

> AJAX Control toolkit

for that or if you are comfortable with javascript and jquery you can also use them for ajax request and partial rendering.